# How to make Python insert an array into a *.c file?

Tags: python, c++, c, arrays

I have a python script that does some computations on a set of data which is a list of floating point decimal numbers. The output is a set of complex numbers that gets separated into a list of real numbers and a list of imaginary numbers, the output is double precision hex floating point.

I would like to have my python script edit a C-file (which is in the same directory as the python script) and insert my lists as arrays at a given line in the C file.

I've tried looking online and couldn't find how to properly transfer the data sets into C

```
input 1(decimal floating point) list = > C (decimal floating point) array
output 1 (hex floating point) list = > C (hex floating point) array 
output 2 (hex floating point) list = > C (hex floating point) array
```

Thank you

Comment: what is the difference between decimal and hex floating point in C?

Comment: You could use python to write a file and then use the #include directive to include it.

Answer (score 3):

The question is about code generation, being C or otherwise has nothing to do with it, C source files are plain text - all you need is file I/O and to output valid C code.

It would perhaps be far simpler however not to modify an existing C source but output your array code directly to a new file and then `#include` that file in the C code - thus using the C preprocessor to insert the code where necessary.